# Como exibir 2 arrays em um foreach?

Tags: php

```
$array1 = ['Hello', 'World'];
$array2 = ['Hello Girl', 'Hello Boy'];

foreach($array1 as $text) 
{ 
  echo $text;]
}
```

Comment: Depende muito do caso, vai de ter 2 foreach ou até se caber na situação um for/foreach e um indice para controlar os itens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


$array = ['Hello', 'World'];
$array2 = ['Hello Girl', 'Hello Boy'];

foreach($array as $indice => $text) 
{ 
  echo $text;
  echo $array2[$indice];
}


?>
```

Desse jeito será impresso o `$array` e depois o `$array2`

Comment: Obrigado Vinicius De Jesus, mas e se eu quisesse fazer com um form usando 2 inputs ? vou editar a pergunta colocando inputs.